# Pass parameters in custom component in angular / ionic4?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to create a costume component to help reduce the repetitive code in my application. The only problem I'm facing is that I can't send parameters into that component.

Comment: please share code what you tried so far

Comment: probably not the right tag; «angular» instead of «angularjs»...

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Comment: @NagaSaiA I didn't try anything tbh I googled it and all I found was Angular related articles I just generated a component with the ionic command ligne.

Comment: @JonathanAnctil no I'm working with ionic 4.0 and it uses AngularJS

Comment: @louk1397 my bad, you were talking about component also. Add some code snippet.

Comment: Ionic4 uses Angular. Here is a friendly reminder: Angular 1.x == AngularJS; Angular 2+ == Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Use bindings.  In your component declaration:

```js
angular.module('app')
        .component('myComponent', {
            bindings: {
                paramA: '<',
                paramB: '<'
            },
            controller: MyControllerConstructor,
            templateUrl: '/path/to/template.html'
        });
```

FYI, the '<' indicates a one way binding from a property on the scope using the component to the component.  This is what you want to use in most cases.

In your HTML:

```html
<my-component param-a="propertyAOnScope" param-b="propertyBOnScope">
</my-component>
```

The passed in values will be properties on your component's controller object.  So within your **component's** controller code:

```js
// get the value passed into paramA
var foo = this.paramA;
```

Comment: I think u answered the question for Angular, not AngularJS

Comment: @louk1397 Nope, what you see here is a feature of Angular**JS**, and you're looking at AngularJS code, not Angular (which is typically written in TypeScript).

Comment: Sadly the OP erroneously tagged this question as AngularJS. Ionic4 uses Angular, not AngularJS.